# During tests, how to override a Django setting used in the urlconf?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing, django-settings

In my Django project's urlconf I have something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^{}/blog'.format(settings.MY_ROOT_DIR),
        include('weblogs.urls')),
    # ...
]
```

In my `settings.py` I'll have something like:

```
MY_ROOT_DIR = 'phil'
```

This is so I can set the root directory, that's used in several places, in one place (the settings).

When I come to test URLs, I use the [`@override_settings` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings):

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.urls import reverse

@override_settings(MY_ROOT_DIR='terry')
class WeblogUrlsTestCase(TestCase):

        def test_post_detail_url(self):
            self.assertEqual(
                reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': 'my-post'}),
                '/terry/blog/my-post/'
            )
```

However, `@override_settings` doesn't appear to do anything - the `MY_ROOT_DIR` value used in `urls.py` is always `"phil"`, never the overridden setting of `"terry"`. I've also tried `@modify_settings`, and using it on the test method, rather than the class.

I guess the urlconf is is loaded by Django before `@override_settings` takes effect? Is there a way around this? Or a better solution altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed, you have overriden settings after they have already been imported in urls. This would have worked if you had used the `settings` variable inside some method, and not in global scope of `urls.py`.

Although overriding settings configuration on runtime might seem convenient, in my opinion, you should create a separate file for testing. This saves a lot of configuration for testing and this would ensure that you never end up doing something irreversible (like cleaning staging database).

```
# test_settings.py

MY_ROOT_DIR = 'terry'
```

Say your testing file exists in 'my_project/test_settings.py', add

```
settings = 'my_project.test_settings' if 'test' in sys.argv else 'my_project.settings'
```

in your manage.py. This will ensure that when you run `python manage.py test` you use test_settings only. If you are using some other testing client like pytest, you could as easily add this to pytest.ini

Comment: Ah, of course. I already have a separate settings file for testing but for some reason hadn't thought of using it for this! My brain must be tired today :) Thanks!

Comment: I had to wait another five minutes before it would let me!

Comment: One DRY trick: You can import your settings at the top of your test settings file, and then you only need to set test settings you want to override.
Ex. `from .settings import *`